# Cannot Update EF Model From Database with TFS

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I've recently moved to using TFS 2012 and have edited a couple of files and checked in without any problems. However, I've just started work on the EF data model and despite being able to open the file the "Update Model From Database" option on the Entity designer right-click menu is greyed out / disabled.

I'm a bit baffled by this.  I've tried checking out the file with the "Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in" but that doesn't make any difference. Nor does checking out the whole folder the project is in.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've discovered that if I create a project in TFS and add an entity model to it then I can update it. However, if I import an existing project into TFS and then try to edit the .edmx file then that's when the problem happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work out the problem, I'll post it here just in case anyone else suffers with this:

The project wasn't set up properly. I was editing the files in the "local path" having not opened the project first (seems kind of stupid now, but this is my first time with TFS and I'd assumed opening the project in TFS opened it as a project in VS).
When I double-clicked on the .csproj file within the Source Control Explorer I was prompted with: "The solution you have opened is under source control but not currently configured for integrated source control in Visual Studio.  Would you like to bind this solution to source control now?"

Clicking "Yes" opened the project correctly and I could run the update the model from the database.