# MVC project with connection string not working for other colleagues in TFS

Tags: c#, sql, tfs, edmx, data-connections

We are working on an MVC application, I added the connection string and generated the data models. When I update the model from database in the .edmx file it updates the web.config file and I check it in TFS. When other other people get latest version from TFS, they see the connection but when they go to the .edmx file it has update the model from database grayed out? is there any way to fix this?

[image: Update model from Database]

Comment: Did the .edmx file on other colleagues' machine are the same with your .edmx file?

Comment: yeah it is, they can now see the models because they had to include in project. But they still cannot update the model from Database, still grayed out for them.

Comment: Refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672171/cannot-update-ef-model-from-database-with-tfs

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your colleagues are opening the project which in source control in VS, not the local one.

Another thing is going into the workspace and change the local path not containing '#' character. More detail info about this, please take a look at this thread: [Entity Framework Unable to refresh database tables under TFS 2010](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f17f95f-a303-45da-ab9f-117725735d69/entity-framework-unable-to-refresh-database-tables-under-tfs-2010?forum=tfsversioncontrol)